# Can't properly assign values to custom datatype matrix cells

Tags: c, matrix

I have defined a custom datatype:

```
typedef CustomDatatype {
   int id;
   OtherCustomDatatype *p;
} CustomDatatype;
```

The thing is I need to work on a 2D `CustomDatatype**` matrix and I need to properly access the cell of the matrix and modify the id field.

```
CustomDatatype **assign_values_to_random_cells(CustomDatatype **matrix, 
const int width, const int n, const int total)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int random_number;
    int i;
    int j;
    int random_value;

    while (counter < n)
    {
        random_number = (rand() % total);
        i = random_number / width;
        j = random_number - (width * i);

        if (perform_a_check(matrix, i, j))
        {
            random_value = random_number%15;
            (*matrix+(random_number))->id = random_value;
            counter++;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Counter: %d ", counter);
        fprintf(stderr, "Value: %d ", (*matrix+(random_number))->id);
        fprintf(stderr, "Position %d (%d, %d)\n", random_number, i, j);
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

As a result this function gives back either less or more random numbers than `n`, which is what I would expect. The same algorithm for an `int **` matrix works absolutely fine, so I am wondering whether I am accessing the matrix cells the right way.

I have tried:

- `matrix[i][j].id = random_value`, which led to duplicate values in addition to the `n` ones I was expecting to see;
- `(*matrix+(cell_number))->id = random_value`, which led to wrongly positioned values and definitely not `n` in number;
- `(*(*matrix+(cell_number))).id = random_value` same as the previous item.

**Update #2:** provides extended output

```
Matrix init:
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 


Counter: 0
Position: 32 (2, 10) (Empty cell!) Value: 2
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   2 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 




Counter: 1
Position: 45 (4, 1) (Empty cell!) Value: 0
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   2 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 




Counter: 2
Position: 64 (5, 9) (Empty cell!) Value: 4
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   2 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   4  -- 
 --   4  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 




Counter: 3
Position: 11 (1, 0) (Empty cell!) Value: 11
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  11  --  -- 
 11  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   2 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   4  -- 
 --   4  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 




Counter: 4
Position: 43 (3, 10) (Empty cell!) Value: 13
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  11  --  -- 
 11  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   2 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  13 
 --  --  13  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   4  -- 
 --   4  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 




Counter: 5
Position: 24 (2, 2) (Empty cell!) Value: 9
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  11  --  -- 
 11  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   9 
 --  --   9  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   2 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  13 
 --  --  13  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -- 
 --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --   4  -- 
 --   4  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stop using random numbers for a moment and use known ones. Then debug it. Then get back to random. It looks your logic is not implementing what you are expecting. Or vice-versa.

Comment: What are these amazing things you want this method to do here? It's quite confusing. Also, as a side note, you don't need to be returning the matrix, as you are acting on it directly and not a copy.

Comment: @Harry I just want to assing a value to a matrix cell randomly chosen when a certain condition is met.

Comment: Your `j` might become negative. Several loops can get the same `i` and `j`, so the location will be assigned more than once. In either case you are not going to get `n` assigned cells (unless you `perform_check` is handling it *correctly*).

Comment: @EugeneSh. `j` is the remainder of `random_number / width` so how can it become negative?

Comment: No, wait. Disregard the previous comment..

Comment: Btw. the situation that `matrix[i][j].id == (i*width+j)%15` cannot happen before you run this code segment?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Well no. The matrix I pass to this function has all cells with `id`s initialized to `0` and then I only write in `matrix[i][j]` if `matrix[i][j].id == 0`.

Comment: So can you provide some example what results you are seeing? Because `matrix[i][j].id = random_number%15;` should definitely work just fine

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I know!! This thing is driving me absolutely crazy. Added sample output.

Comment: Print the entire matrix after each step for starters.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I am noticing that for some of the elements, it assigns the value to the cell and the cell that is three spots ahead.

Comment: Plus `0` is handled badly, as it triggers the `matrix[i][j].id == (i*width+j)%15` condition.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I am sorry, I lost you on this one, what you mean with `it triggers the matrix[i][j].id == (i*width+j)%15`?

Comment: It might have to do with what exactly is passed as the first parameter to `assign_values_to_random_cells`.  How is that variable declared?

Comment: @dbush what you mean how declared? At first is `NULL`, then `malloc()` to allocate space and then an init function to set all `id`s to `0`.

Comment: Is it declared as `CustomDatatype **matrix;`?  What exactly do you pass to `malloc()`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be figured out your remark, added `+1` to `random_value = random_number%15;` but still...

Comment: @dbush the first malloc I perform is `matrix = (CustomDatatype **) malloc (width * sizeof(CustomDatatype *));` and then `matrix[i] = (CustomDatatype *) malloc (height * sizeof(CustomDatatype));`

Comment: @dbush that was it!! I have switched `width` with `height` in the cycle that performs `malloc()` and now seems to work!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I do not completely understand what you are trying to achieve but:

- you are writing values to random positions, therefore there is no guarantee that you will write N unique values if you do this process N times
- `cell_number` is never initialized

Comment: Oops... you're right, I got confused cell_number is in fact random_number. I just want to assing a value to a matrix cell randomly chosen when a certain condition is met.

Comment: And (stupidly) I forgot to mention that  `perform_a_check() ` makes sure that the cell is not already used.